# Converting an EXISTS block to NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, exists

Let say part of my query has a statement that says:

```
... AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dogs d WHERE d.name = 'Jack')
```

How can I convert the EXISTS to NOT EXISTS?

I tried inverting the conditions in the SELECT part but it doesn't give the same output as before.

**EDIT: To clarify - I want to rewrite the same part of my query using NOT EXISTS instead of EXISTS and still achieve the same result from the query.**

EDIT2: Nevermind, ignore this please!

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: You type `NOT` between `AND` and `EXISTS`, but I suspect that is not really what you are asking.  Describe what you are trying to achieve and what is not working correctly.

Comment: To clarify - I want to rewrite the same part of my query using NOT EXISTS instead of EXISTS and still achieve the same result from the query.

Comment: @Jelly1234 I don't really see a point in this... it's working now, right?

Comment: Actually, I figured out that I shouldn't even need this part. It seems pointless but that is because it is for homework. In my homework, I can combine this whole thing with another NOT EXISTS test instead of adding this part

Comment: `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dogs d WHERE d.name <> 'Jack')` ????